# Create new instance in Oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, instance

I installed Oracle 11g, with ad instance called orcl.

And I want to create another instance, called for example orcl1.

How could I do that? Do I nead to re-install another database like I did the first time?

Comment: Why do you think you need a second instance? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: I have a project devided in two under projects that use two databases.  When I imported the second database in the same instance, I had some error of connecting with database. So I wanted to create two instances, instance 1 for the database 1, and instance 2 for the database 2.

Comment: If we knew more about "some error of connecting with database" perhaps that could/should be addressed. Especially since you appear to be wanting to create a second instance purely as a work-around.  But to answer your specific question - Installing the software is not the same as creating a database/instance.  YOu don't need to reinstall, any more than you would "re-install" MS Office just because you want to create another Word document.

Comment: Does your project need to connect to two hard-coded identical schema names?

Comment: Would it be enough if you just use another schema, instead of another database?

Comment: I dont thini, I tried everything but nothing seems to work. So I thought maybe if I made each database for each instance, it would work.

Comment: We don't know the "everything" that you tried, or why "nothing" seemed to work.  If we knew the details of a specific "something" you tried, and the details of "didn't work", we could probably fix you right up.  I, and I think others, suspect that your concept of 'schema', 'database', and 'instance' are incorrect and leading you down a rabbit hole. They don't mean the same thing in oracle as they do in MSSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either to use :

1. DBCA : recommended because easier. See [example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/create002.htm) (this assumes that Oracle executables have already been installed).

or

2. CREATE DATABASE SQL statement with SQL*Plus: [more complex.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/create003.htm#CIAEJDBE)